# Can i drill through in power BI just by clicking on the cell in the table?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have incorporated my drill through feature in my reports. However, drill through is possible by right clicking the cell and then choosing the "drill-through".
Is there an option that I can simply select the cell in the table and the drill through happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct click option for drill trough. But you can use an alternative using **Drill Through** button. To make a button enable for Drill Through, just add a **Blank** button and configure as below-

[image]

Finally, implement the Drill Through for example in a **table visual**. Now, when you **click** on a table row, the **Drill Through** button will be **enabled**. By click on the button you can now go to the details page.

Comment: Okay thank you for this insight! 
This worked. 
I also created a DAX measure to make the name of the button dynamic!!

Comment: Wow great! nice to hear it helped and worked. You can also put an up vote :)